# React Native Android wont Build .APK: ...Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler

Tags: gradle, react-native

I am trying to use my Mac to export an Android build of my React Native project with

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

but I sadly get an error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler
```

Has anyone encountered this?/Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Change JAVA_HOME to point to Java 8

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: Thank you Vasily, 

I searched the entire project for `export JAVA_HOME` and it didn't exist. `set JAVA_HOME` does in `gradlew.bat`.

Should I add the line? Is there a specific place I should be seeing it that I can look?

Comment: I realize now that you mean to add that in terminal:  `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home`

Sweet. Now i'm in another issue, but I may just be past this!

Answer (score 0):

try

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer`
4. `javac -version`
   [image]
5. `sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default`